# Generate a diff report on json in python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, regression, diff

I have a regression test script in python which takes in a JSON from ground truth file and JSON from a rest api and if they don't match I want to generate diff. The script is in python. I can walk through JSON and compare line by line but challenge is  new element can be appended in the end or start or middle. Then line by line  can get complicated. Is there some library that can spit the diff out if two JSON strings are passed.

Comment: [Built-in difflib](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/difflib.html) might be a step in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the `deepdiff` package. Here is an example with it:

```
from deepdiff import DeepDiff

t1 = {'a': 10, 'b': 20}
t2 = {'a': 10, 'b': 22}
ddiff = DeepDiff(t1, t2, ignore_order=True)
print(ddiff)
```

This prints:

```
{'values_changed': {"root['b']": {'new_value': 22, 'old_value': 20}}}
```

Comment: I see an issue: Python 3.6.4 (v3.6.4:d48ecebad5, Dec 18 2017, 21:07:28) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from deepdiff import DeepDiff
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/Users/rchikka@us.ibm.com/Downloads/RegressionTesting/deepdiff.py", line 1, in <module>
    from deepdiff import DeepDiff
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepDiff'

Comment: @javaMan change your `deepdiff.py` file name to something else. That's the reason of this import error.